# How to access an Android 7.0 phone via MTP from terminal?

Tags: android, mtp

I can't figure out, how to access an Android 7.0 phone's storage via MTP from terminal?

Phone: Honor 8

System: Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit

I can access it via Nemo file manager as:

```
mtp://[usb:003,002]/
```

But I can't see it inside neither:

```
/var/run/user/$UID/gvfs/
```

, nor inside:

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs/
```

I also tried to find it via `mount` command to list all of the mounted devices:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8131796k,nr_inodes=2032949,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1631104k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=38,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13805)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1631104k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/dev/sr0 on /media/vlastimil/My CDROM type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)
```

But I see there is only `/dev/sr0`.

My phone shows 2 devices in file manager:

1. My CDROM:

   ```
   /media/vlastimil/My CDROM
   ```

   with the contents to be Windows program to control the phone.
2. FRD L09:

   ```
   mtp://[usb:003,002]/
   ```

   with contents being Internal storage and SD card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Debian 9, there's a FUSE-based filesystem `jmtpfs`, packaged with the same name. It seems to work quite well with Android 8 at least. Perhaps it is available as a package for Mint too?

As it's a real FUSE filesystem, it is actually mountable, and so usable from the command line.

The source code and the developer's introduction to `jmtpfs` is [here](https://github.com/JasonFerrara/jmtpfs).